# AssertionError Fleiss' Kappa for IAA

Tags: python, cohen-kappa

In my data frame

```
data = {'Query' : ['Carpal Ts', 'Dermallxde'],
        'Items' : [['Sir chucks', 'Oga Mathew', 'Tambe Charlse'],['Man Ond', 'kolofata Hil', 'Haruna mendy']],
        'Raters' : [[[0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]],[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]]}
```

`results_df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

The Raters rates either 0/1 for for each query rates Items as bad or good  respectively.

I have tried to calculate the Fleiss' Kappa by creating an matrix array for the raters column and for each Item row i get the Fleiss' Kappa for that particular Query.
Please see my attempt below

```
from statsmodels.stats.inter_rater import fleiss_kappa

# create an empty list to hold the Fleiss' Kappa values
kappas = []

# iterate over each index in the results dataframe
for idx, row in results_df.iterrows():
    data = row['Raters'] # get the list of lists in the 'Data' field
    users = row['Items'] # get the list of users with data
    
    # check if there are exactly three non-null columns with lists of equal length
    if len(data) == 3 and len(set([len(d) for d in data])) == 1:
        kappa = fleiss_kappa(np.array(data).T)
        print(kappa)
        kappas.append({
            'Query': idx,
            'Items': users,
            'Fleiss Kappa': kappa
        })

# create a new dataframe from the list of Fleiss' Kappa values
kappa_df = pd.DataFrame(kappas)
```

**Any help on this Calculation will be much appreciated.**

Comment: Can you provide *any* details about this `AssertionError`?

Comment: @ScottHunter no details as it returns nothing. i get "AssertionError: " any other way to get the kappa will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. If I understand your data correctly, you need to first convert data with shape (subject, rater) to (subject, cat_counts), as described [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.inter_rater.aggregate_raters.html#statsmodels.stats.inter_rater.aggregate_raters).
So before computing kappa, convert the data to the (subject, cat_count) shape by using aggregate_raters() function. Hope this helps!

```
from statsmodels.stats.inter_rater import fleiss_kappa,aggregate_raters

# create an empty list to hold the Fleiss' Kappa values
kappas = []

# iterate over each index in the results dataframe
for idx, row in results_df.iterrows():
    data = row['Raters'] # get the list of lists in the 'Data' field
    users = row['Items'] # get the list of users with data
    
    # check if there are exactly three non-null columns with lists of equal length
    if len(data) == 3 and len(set([len(d) for d in data])) == 1:
        kappa = fleiss_kappa(aggregate_raters(np.array(data).T)[0])
        print(kappa)
        kappas.append({
            'Query': idx,
            'Items': users,
            'Fleiss Kappa': kappa
        })

# create a new dataframe from the list of Fleiss' Kappa values
kappa_df = pd.DataFrame(kappas)
```